# redirect htaccess rule for node express application

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, express, redirect

my node js application is serving pages on port 3000, and to redirect here when user type for example

http://pctechtips.org/apps/nodetest

I'm adding this to my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

But I'm not getting my node/express app displaying "hello world" Is this rule correct. This is meant to work on a share hosting service with cPanel. 
here's my express route

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

//=========== Express Routes Here ==========//
//default route
app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.send("Hello Node.js");
});

//catch all other routes
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
        res.send("Invalid Page");
});

//server listening on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log("server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Added an answer, is that what you wanted? Maybe add a result of what you would expect as result from your input url

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect everything to localhost:3000

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L]
```